# How to display LayeredPane in CardLayout

Tags: java, swing

i have problem with switch Panel in Card Layout. I create card layout and i add to this some Panels. When i try switch Panel text from jLabel2 doesn't appear, but i think, that Panel was change.

```js
panelGlowny = new javax.swing.JLayeredPane();
losowaniePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
test = new javax.swing.JButton();
.....
panelGlowny.setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());
jLabel2.setText("Losowanie Panel");
javax.swing.GroupLayout losowaniePanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(losowaniePanel);
        losowaniePanel.setLayout(losowaniePanelLayout);
        losowaniePanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            losowaniePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(losowaniePanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(162, 162, 162)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addContainerGap(160, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
panelGlowny.add(losowaniePanel, "card2");

test.setText("test");
        test.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                testActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

.....
 private void testActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        losowanie_panel();
    }   
.....

public void losowanie_panel()
    {
        panelGlowny.removeAll();
        panelGlowny.add(losowaniePanel);
        invalidate();
        repaint();
    }
```

Comment: Your basic understanding of CardLayout is incorrect. You should not be using code like removeAll() and add(...). The point of using a CardLayout is to create two separate panels. Each panel will contain the components you want to display. Then you use the CardLayout to swap between the two panels. There should be no need for the layered pane. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for working examples to get you started. If you need more help post a proper [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: See: [combine effects of CardLayout and JLayeredPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769412/java-swing-combine-effects-of-cardlayout-and-jlayeredpane)